# How can I evaluate my android app latency measure (give me name of tool)

Tags: android, performance, latency

How Can I evaluate my android app through my phone

I want name of the tool to measure latency time that I can download through my android phone or any tool that can help me to measure it ... (latency time for the integrated system in my app)

please I want someone to help me with that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Measuring latency doesn't mean much if you don't specify what you are measuring, graphics render time, memory access, layout time, network latency and more. Please do some more research using your favorite search engine.

Comment: You could user Android Profiler which is located at the bottom and center of the Android Studio. However, you still need to search on how Android Profiler shows the insights.